# Wordpress: align the email notification and follow up on comments

Tags: css, wordpress

I have installed jetpack and activated email notification and follow up on comments. These fields are showing below the comment box but they are not aligned(for reference this is my blog link: http://techiedreams.com/test/

Please tell me changes can i do to align them properly as the 'commentluv'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with commentluv Plugin. I have deactivated the commentluv plugin and the Problem has solved.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `Notify Me...` texts are labels. In your CSS you have defined

```
#comment-form label {
  float: left;
  width: 110px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}
```

Setting the width to 110px which works for the rest of the form, but you can override these individually because they each have the ID's of `#subscribe-label` and `#subscribe-blog-label` respectively.

So place in your CSS

```
#subscribe-label, #subscribe-blog-label { width: auto; }
```

You might want to put a bit of padding on the right so that the checkboxes are spaced out a little.

Comment: Thanks for your reply deadlyhifi. Some changes to your answer i solved the width problem:#comment-form label.subscribe-label, #comment-form label.subscribe-blog-label { 
width: auto; 
}
now problem with aligning the check boxes please help me with that!

Comment: You could just put `margin-right: 25px;` into the declaration you just did to push them out a little.

Comment: Hi deadlyhifi, can u please tell me the exact solution so that i can align the check box just below the 'comment luv' in my blog: http://techiedreams.com/test/ . My problem is am not able to get the reference to the checkboxes from the css.

Comment: I can't see now as you've taken them away on your site.

Comment: Yes i used Jetpack and i think problem with the comment luv plugin i disabled it and the new comment box is shown with a proper alignment. anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a small change in your CSS.

In your style.css line number 1699, change the width to `70%`.

```
#respond textarea {
width: 70%;
}
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: Sorry this is for aligning the textarea.